# Add Java Libraries to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am quite new to Java and Eclipse.

I am trying to call some functions from the [jpf library](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/) from a program that I am writing in Eclipse.

Can anyone help me load or install these libraries into my Eclipse project?  The .zip files are [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpf/files/jpf-1.5/jpf-1.5.1/).  If these are already in the Eclipse program or there is some better way to get them, can someone also post that answer in addition to how to load any arbitrary java library.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Follow the instructions [on the jpf page itself](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/ide-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 1):

The JPF project page, to which you already linked in your question, contains a section about [setting up the Eclipse IDE for JPF projects](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/ide-eclipse.html). A more general webpage on [how to add external jars to your eclipse project](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) might be helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract `jpf-bin-1.5.1.zip`.  In here, you will find one or more JAR files.  Add them into your Eclipse project, under something like a "lib" folder.  Right-click on the JAR files from there, then choose "Build Path" / "Add to Build Path".

Or better yet, investigate the use of Apache Maven, and let it handle all of the dependency resolution for you.  (Per http://jpf.sourceforge.net/roadmap.html, this project is at least Maven-enabled.) At least the 1.5 version is also available from the central Maven repository at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jpf/jpf/.  I don't see 1.5.1, but the `jpf-bin-1.5.1.zip` contains a "MAVEN.txt" that explains how to install it into a local Maven repository for use.

Answer (score 0):

download desired jar in to your local machine - add those jar to your project using below

> right click on your project - configure build path - libraries - add
>   external jars - browse downloaded jars - add

Answer (score 0):

check how add libraries in eclipse.
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_an_extra_library_to_my_project%27s_classpath%3F

Also check this how make user libraries in Eclipse and then add them in your project.
http://i-proving.com/2006/07/18/user-libraries-in-eclipse